Chi-squared divergence inequalities proof using Cauchy-Schwarz
I am trying to prove the two following inequalities for distributions $P$ and $Q$ with densities $p$ and $q$ respectively, using the Chi-squared divergence defined as:
$$\mathcal{X}^2(p||q) = \int\frac{(p-q)^2}{q} d\mu$$

$\left|\mathbb{E}_p[x] - \mathbb{E}_q[x]\right| \leq \sqrt{\mathcal{X}^2(p||q)} . \sqrt{\mathbf{\text{Var}}_q(x)}$
$|\mathbb{E}_p\left[x^2\right] - \mathbb{E}_q\left[x^2\right]| \leq \sqrt{\mathcal{X}^2(p||q)} . \sqrt{\mathbb{E}_q\left[x^4\right]}$

I managed to prove the second inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz($\left(\mathbb{E}[XY]\right)^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]. \mathbb{E}[Y^2])$:
$$\left(\int (p - q)x^2 \hspace{0.2cm}dx\right)^2 = \left(\int \frac{p - q}{q} x^2 q \hspace{0.1cm}dx \right)^2 = \left(\mathbb{E}_q\left[\frac{(p-q)}{q}x^2\right]\right)^2$$
$$ \leq \mathbb{E}_q\left[\frac{(p-q)^2}{q^2}\right] .\mathbb{E}_q\left[x^4\right] = \mathcal{X}^2(p||q) .\mathbb{E}_q\left[x^4\right]$$
But using the same method for the first inequality yields $\mathcal{X}^2(p||q) .\mathbb{E}_q\left[x^2\right]$ for the right-hand side. I cannot seem to find a way to use Cauchy to derive $\mathbf{\text{Var}}_q(x)$. I would really appreciate any hints.

Note that the denominator of the divergence is $q$, not $q^2$

Sure, but when you take the expected value it gets multiplied by $q$ and we get the definition of $\mathcal{X}$.

$$\begin{align}
\left|\mathbb{E}_p[X] - \mathbb{E}_q[X]\right|
&= \left| \int x \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}-1 \right)q(x) d\mu(x)\right|
\\&= \left| \int (x-\mathbb E_q[X]+ \mathbb E_q[X]) \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}-1 \right)q(x) d\mu(x)\right|
\\&=\left| \int (x-\mathbb E_q[X]) \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}-1 \right)q(x) d\mu(x) + \mathbb E_q[X]\int p(x)-q(x) d\mu(x)\right|
\\&= \left| \int (x-\mathbb E_q[X]) \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}-1 \right)q(x) d\mu(x) \right|
\\&\leq  \sqrt{\mathcal{X}^2(p||q)}  \sqrt{\mathbf{\text{Var}}_q(X)},
\end{align}
$$
where the last inequality is obtained via Cauchy-Schwarz.
